# How to implement View Pager same Fragment in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager

I wanna ask if there any best way to implement view pager with only one fragment in Kotlin?

Comment: You want to use single fragment once, or the same fragment with different instance?

Comment: same fragment with different instance @Aziz

Comment: Check my answer @Vanya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like if you have a ViewPager Adapter like below

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

val fragments:MutableList<Fragment> = ArrayList()
val titles:MutableList<String> = ArrayList()

fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title:String){
    fragments.add(fragment)
    titles.add(title)
}

override fun getItem(p0: Int): Fragment = fragments[p0]

override fun getCount(): Int = fragments.size

override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
    return titles[position]
}


override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
    super.destroyItem(container, position, `object`)
}

}
```

Now if you have fragment, `SampleFragment` (say)

Just call the method with whichever fragment you want,

```
adapter.addFragment(SampleFragment(),"Sample Fragment")
..
..
adapter.addFragment(SampleFragment(),"Sample Fragment 2")
```

Comment: Thanks, I should send the data inside fragment to comparing with other view

Comment: Yep, you just need to create different bundle for different instance of fragment

Answer (score 0):

Create model class `FragmentConfig` where you going to keep parameters for fragment.

Add array of configs `fragmentConfigs` to your `FragmentPagerAdapter`
and in adapter:

```
 override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        val fragmentConfig = fragmentConfigs[position]
        return UniversalListFragment.newInstance(fragmentConfig)
    }
```